Who is the "singular Lord of all lords" in heaven at Deuteronomy 10:17? And who is the "singular Lord of lords in heaven at Revelation 17:14?
Deuteronomy 10:17, "For the Lord your God is the God of gods and the Lord of lords, the great, the mighty and awesome God who does not show partiality, nor take a bribe."
Revelation 17:14, "These will wage war against the Lamb, and the Lamb will overcome them, because He is Lord of lords and King of kings, and those who are with Him are the called and chosen and faithful."
Do these two verses compliment each other and prove that Jesus is deity like His Father?

There is no contradiction.  Let us be clear:
In the OT, YHWH is called "Lord of Lords"

Deut 10:17 - For the LORD your God is God of gods and Lord of lords, the great, mighty, and awesome God, showing no partiality and accepting no bribe.
Ps 136:3 - Give thanks to the Lord of lords.

In the NT, Jesus as "The Lamb" is also called "Lord of Lords"

Rev 17:14 - They will make war against the Lamb, and the Lamb will triumph over them, because He is Lord of lords and King of kings; and He will be accompanied by His called and chosen and faithful ones.”
Rev 19:16 - And He [Jesus] has a name having been written upon the robe and upon His thigh: King of Kings and Lord of Lords.

We may go further with numerous other titles such as:

"Lord of All": in the OT this is YHWH Deut 10:17, Josh 3:11, 13, Ps 97:5, Zech 4:14, 6:5, Mic 4:13; but in the NT we have this applied to Jesus Acts 10:36, Rom 10:12
The "Light": in the OT this YHWH Ps 27:1, Micah 7:8, Isa 9:2; in the NT this is Jesus John 1:4, 5, 9, 8:12, 9:5, 1 John 1:5-7, Matt 4:15, 16
Unique "Savior" Isa 43:3, 11, 14, 44:24, 45:17, 21, 49:7 vs Matt 1:21; Acts 4:12; 2 Tim 1:10; Tit 1:4, 2:13, 3:6; 2 Pet 1:1, 11
Unique divine "Shepherd" Psalm 23:1; Eze 34:11ff, Isa 40:11, Ps 95:7, 100:3 vs John 10:11-16; Heb 13:20, 1 Peter 2:25, 5:4; Rev 7:17
"First and Last" Isa 41:4, 44:6, 48:12 vs Rev 1:17, 18, 2:8, 22:13
Unique "Creator" Isa 44:24, 45:18 (Ps 33:6, 9) vs John 1:3, 10, Col 1:16, 17, Heb 1:2, 10
Unique glory Isa 42:8, 48:11 vs John 17:5, 24
etc.

APPENDIX - "King of kings"
There is another question here that I will not answer but only mention entirely in the NT.  There are only two places where "King of kings" occurs in the whole Bible, viz:

1 Tim 6:14, 15 - Keep this commandment without stain or reproach until the appearance of our Lord Jesus Christ, 15which the blessed and only Sovereign One—the King of kings and Lord of lords—will bring about in His own time.
Rev 19:16 - And He [Jesus] has a name written on His robe and on His thigh: KING OF KINGS AND LORD OF LORDS.

Assuming that the first applies to the Father and the second to the Son, is there a need to reconcile these or accept them as either statements of fact or a statement of absolute unity such as that in Rev 22:3 where "God and of the Lamb" is referenced by the singular "His" and "Him".

I don’t see these at odds. The Spirit, the Son (the lamb) and God the father are one. He is Lord of Lords, God (The Elohim) of gods (elohim):
John 1:1-2, 14 (NIV): “In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God. He was with God in the beginning… The Word became flesh and made his dwelling among us. We have seen his glory, the glory of the one and only Son, who came from the Father, full of grace and truth.”

Who is the singular Lord of lords in Deuteronomy 10:17? The verse itself answers the question. It is YHWH/Jehovah.
Who is the singular Lord of lords in Revelation 17:14? Again, the verse itself answer the question. It is the Lamb.
Deuteronomy 10:17 compliments the YHWH. Revelation 17:14 compliments Jesus.
Do these verses prove Jesus is deity like his Father? No these verses do not prove Jesus is deity like his Father.
Deuteronomy 10:17 does not identify Jesus as YHWH because Jesus was never called God of gods. YHWH has no Father, He is the Father.
Revelation 4:8 shows the Almighty God (Jesus was never called Almighty God) sitting on the throne worshipped because He created everything. Revelation 5:6 shows the  "Lamb standing, as if slaughtered," and was worshipped because his shedding of his blood ransomed mankind for God.
John the Baptist identified Jesus in John 1:29 as the "Lamb of God". Clearly then the Lamb has a God, Revelation 1:1 shows us that Jesus is not God for it shows that his God gave him revelations. Revelation 3:12 show Jesus calling his God "my God" four times.
"King of kings" is a title that has been applied to men like Artaxerxes (Ezra 7:12) and Nebuchadnezzar (Ezekiel 26:12) before. The applications of titles does not make the person sharing the title God.
The titles applied to Jesus are best explained with what we find in John 12:44 "And Jesus cried and said, He that believeth on me, believeth not on me, but on him that sent me". Oversimplification regarding title application causes title confusion. The lamb in Revelation is not God. God was not killed and had to be resurrected by his God.

You said, "YHWH has no Father, He is the Father." John 3:16 teaches that Jesus Christ is the one and ONLY Son of God. Can you give me an example of a son that does not share the same nature as its father? Revelation 1:7-8 identifies Jesus as the Lord God who is and who was and who is to come, the Almighty. The Father is not coming, the Son is. You said "King of kings" is applied to men. These men are dead and no longer "King of kings." The Father is the Lord of heaven and so is Jesus Christ and obviously both are alive. Btw, others in the NT identified Jesus Christ as Lord and God

@Mr.Bond. Jesus was never called the Lord God nor the Almighty in the bible. Revelation 1:8 is in reference to God, and not to Christ is that the word “almighty” (pantokratōr, Strong’s #3841 παντοκράτωρ) is only used of God in scripture (2 Cor. 6:18; Rev. 4:8; 15:3; 16:7; 19:15; 21:22). He is the only “almighty” one, there is no other.
